# How much memory takes empty Runnable class?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, runnable

I was googling, but I did not found good answer for my question:

How much memory takes empty Runnable class?

I am asking for it because I do not know what is better in some cases - creating my own sheduler with single runnable inside that will be executed every X time until aplication will close, or init new Runnable everytime when I want to do something not in main thread and put code directly to this.

Comment: I guess this is an XY problem. You are working under a memory managed language which mostly take care about how and when allocate/deallocate memory. I'd say to totally ignore the problem and do the one which suits you best until you prove that its memory consumption is a problem (which is very unlikely to happen).

Comment: Sorry, the question makes no sense.  The amount of memory consumed by an "empty" runnable will be so tiny as to be unnoticeable.  You are worrying about what is certainly premature optimization.

Comment: The memory required for an (instance of?) an empty class is less than the memory required for this comment. That is, a few bytes. Unless you are creating millions of "empty objects" per second, this is highly irrelevant. (I'm **not** downvoting, though. If you extended your question with more information, it *could* actually make some sense....)

Comment: It is not that simple as you think. Runnable extends Thread and thread may take a lot of memory just by initation. I have created 1000 empty new runnables on 256M and my application freezed.

Comment: `Runnable` is an _interface_ and does not extend `Thread`, `Thread` _implements_ `Runnable`.  A `Runnable` by itself takes NO memory.  Your implementation may consume memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal size for an instance of a class that implements `Runnable` is 8 bytes.  (That's the size of an object with no fields on a 32 or 64 bit JVM.) The actual size will depend on the specific implementation.

> It is not that simple as you think. `Runnable extends Thread` and thread may take a lot of memory just by initialization.

Your reasoning is incorrect.

A `Thread` instance takes a lot of space because it has a thread stack, not because it implements `Runnable`.  Furthermore, the space for the thread stacks is not allocated when the thread is initialized.  It is allocated when you call `Thread.start()`.

Also, if you are using `Thread` objects as `Runnable` instances, then you are probable using the `Thread` API incorrectly.  The recommended way to use `Thread` and `Runnable` is to declare an *independent* class that implements `Runnable` (not `Thread`!).  Then, either pass a `Runnable` instance to the `Thread` constructor, or (better) submit a `Runnable` instance to a thread pool executor service or similar.

Extending `Thread` has been recognized to be a bad idea since the days of Java 1.1.

> I created 1000 empty new runnables on 256M and my application froze.

The freeze is unlikely to be anything to do with memory utilization of simple `Runnable` instances.

But if you created and started 1000 threads, then that *could* get you into trouble.  An application with that many threads is liable to have serious performance issues.  But even then the memory utilization of the thread stacks won't cause a freeze.  (If the JVM runs out of memory, you will get an `OutOfMemoryError` ... not a freeze, unless you have turned off the GC overhead limit protection.)

It is likely that the freeze has occurred for other reasons; e.g. your threads may have deadlocked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I was creating new Runnable, and I was putting code into method run(). Now I understand that better is to create sheduler (or something like this) that will implement Runnable and run code in smallest amount of thread as it is possible.

Comment: @PiotrOsada - Putting the code into the `Runnable.run()` is the correct thing to do.  Indeed, if you are using one of the standard Java scheduler classes (like an `ExecutorService` then you *have* to submit the tasks as instances of `Runnable` or `Callable`.  As I said, your freezing problem is most lilkely due to something else; e.g. what the `run()` methods are doing.

Comment: The freezing problem was due to async runnable. I was using BukkitRunnable.runTaskAsynchronously(args..) in Bukkit API (fork of minecraft server). Also, not only application have been freezed - it was freezing my server machine probably because of too many threads.

Comment: @PiotrOsada Using an ExecutorService will allow you to fire off Runnable tasks without creating too many threads. e.g. you can limit it to 1 or 4 threads for example regardless of the number of tasks.